# How to sort list of float values with None in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list with None values. How to sort this list ?

```
res = sorted(res, key=itemgetter(sort_field), reverse = reverse)
```

return error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < float()
```

Comment: Where would you expect them to be sorted?

Comment: You'll need to write a sort key function that handles them appropriately (e.g. turns them into `float('inf')` or `-float('inf')` or something else (depending on where you want them to show up)